# Get Foreign key data in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relation

I have two tables room and room_images. In room_images table, we have multiple images of one room. Now i want to show those images in room edit blade template.

```
    rooms table:   | room_image table:
    id (PK)        | id
    title          | room_id (FK)
    desc           | room_image
```

**Room Edit Controller**

```
`public function edit($id)
 { 
    $room = Room::find($id);
    if(auth()->user()->id !== $room->user_id){
        return redirect('/rooms')->withStatus(__('Unauthorized Page'));
    }
    return view('rooms.edit')->with('room' , $room);
 }`
```

**Room Modal: Room.php**

```
`public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
 }
 public function tbl_roomimages()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\RoomImage');
 }`
```

**Room Image Modal: RoomImage.php**

```
`public function tbl_rooms()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Room','room_id');
 }`
```

Here is the database column pictures:
[Room images tbl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xw8on.png)

[Room tbl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kAcr.png)

Comment: You should not store images in your database, you could use the Storage that laravel provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should return the instance of the relationship from your model.

```
$roomImages = $room->tbl_roomimages()->get();
```

You will be able to access the column data from tbl_roomimages like

```
foreach($roomImages as $roomImage)
{
     $roomImage->room_image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I've got a couple things for ya. Let's see how I do.

**First, the issue with your Models:**

You have the relationship functions named with a leading "tbL_" which in Laravel is going to affect the foreign key they look for. Instead, you need to use snake case. So, for instance, your Room-RoomImages relationship needs to be this:

```
 public function room_images()
 {
    return $this->hasMany('App\RoomImage');
 }`
```

*[Quick note: this might actually just be a standard naming convention. It's good practice either way, but I might be wrong on the foreign key connection. Feel free to call me out on it.]*

**Then, the Controller**

Then, just as a matter of efficiency, I recommend "eager-loading" your room images. So, in the controller, change over to this:

```
$room = Room::with("room_images")->find($id);
```

**Then, finally, in your view**

Assuming "room_image" is actually a "src" value, do this:

```
@foreach($room->room_images as $img)

   <img src="{{ $img->room_image }}" />

@endforeach
```

And, assuming that is indeed just the src path, I'd really recommend changing the field name to reflect that to avoid confunsion.

**Now, a couple tips:**

One: "Modal" -> "Model." (A Modal is a pop-up window.)

Two: if you use compact(), you can save yourself a lot of redundancy in the event you have lots of variables to pass to the view.

```
return view('rooms.edit')->with(compact('room', 'room_images', 'otherthing'));
```